# complete control over the CSS for tooltipsy

Tags: jquery, html, css, tooltip

How to control css for tooltipsy? i failed to applied it. please check the demo with the below jsfiddle link.I'm trying to apply the same css as this  [tooltipsy](http://tooltipsy.com/) but it's not working. ANy help would be appreciated.

Current code :`1` [JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ysuw5/230/)

`<script src="js/tooltipsy.min.js"></script>`

Comment: how to include? never use mootools before

Comment: Sorry, question must be "Why do you include mootools in your fiddle?". When i replaced with jQuery 1.8.3 it doesn't work either. Are you sure the fiddle working?

Comment: Sorry . my mistake. i've changed it to jquery v11.. yet still cant work...

Comment: Please include tooltipsy's css and js files via "External Resources" on jsfiddle.